# Can't get os-service app working except from command line

Tags: node.js, powershell, express

I have a node.js app that I want to run as a windows service, and I'm using os-service to try to achieve that.

The service installs seemingly correctly, and the Windows Services management console provides this info about it:

In the listing:

```
Name: wibble
Description: (blank)
Status: (blank)
Startup Type: automatic
Log On As: Local System
```

In the properties/General pane:
Path to executable:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\path\to\app.js" "--run"
```

Attempting to start this service using powershell thus

```
Start-Service wibble
```

produces an error message containing: *Cannot start service wibble on computer '.'*

Attempting to start this service from the management interface's "Start the Service" link with the service selected in the Services manager yields a different error message: *Windows could not start the wibble service on Local Computer. Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.*

The following works, when executed from a powershell in same folder as the app. Clients can connect to and use the app successfully:

```
node app.js --run
```

However, the powershell stops at that point until CTRL+C stops the service.

Here's the JS I added to the app to get it to run as a service:

```
var service = require('os-service');
var fs = require('fs');

process.chdir(__dirname);
if (process.argv[2] == '--run') {
    var fn = process.env.LOCALAPPDATA + '/path/to/wibble.log';
    var logStream = fs.createWriteStream (fn);
    service.run (logStream, function () {
        'use strict';
        service.stop (0);
    });
    // rest of app here
}
module.exports = app
```

Hopefully I've overlooked something dumb. My gratitude if you can spot it!

Comment: Does your application, by any chance, use childprocess.fork at any point to spawn child processes? I'm having a similar problem and it seems to be related to that.

Comment: Certainly not explicitly. It's possible that some of the modules I load (express, mongodb, monk, morgan) do so implicitly. I fixed my problem by using node-windows which I think is superior on 2 counts: 1) it works for me, 2) it requires zero changes to the node.js app, just the creation of a utility to install/start/stop/remove it as a service.